# How to filter elements in list of classes by another list?

Tags: dart

I want to generate `List<String>` from list of classes.

For simplification I am generation names as `{$i name}`. So I am expecting to get:

```
["2 name", "4 name", "5 name"]
```

```
class MyClass {
  late int id;
  late String name;
  
  MyClass({required this.id, required this.name});
  
}

List<MyClass> mcList = [];

void main() {
  
  List<int> list = [2,4,5];
  
  for(var i in [1,2,3,4,5]) {
    MyClass mc = MyClass(id: i, name: '{$i name}');
    mcList.add(mc);
  }
  
//  var x = mcList.where((e) => list.contains(e['i'])).toList();
//  print(x);
   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's what you're looking for:

```
  var x = mcList.where((e) => list.contains(e.id)).map((obj) => obj.name).toList();
```

I simply fixed your `where` function and transformed the result, which was a `List<MyClass>` into a `List<String>` as you wanted using the `map` function.